# Inner product (functions) tending to infinity

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, galerkin-methods

I have a quite simple question, which I'm not really able to answer. Assume that you have to functions $f,g$ on an infinite dimensional function (normed) space. Define the usual inner product on a given interval $[0,b]$ as $$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_{0}^{b} f(t)g(t)dt$$

Now assume that I would like to approximate the function $f$ by a suitable finite subset of basis functions $\{\phi_i\}_{i}^{N}$, which can be done by using the aforementioned inner product.

Ok, my question is the following: Can I define this inner product if $b\to\infty$? Do I need any hypothesis on the set of $\phi$'s or the function $f$?

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Defining an the inner product  on  a space of functions on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal B_\Omega,dx)$ boils down to Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, which provides the estimate
$$
\left|\int_{\Omega}fgdx\right|\le \left(\int_\Omega f^2dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_\Omega g^2dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
Hence you could define your inner product on the vector space of continuous square integrable functions on $[0,\infty)$, i.e. $f\in C[0,\infty)$ such that $\int_0^\infty f^2dx<\infty$ (where Cauchy-Schwarz proves linearity of the space). Then to obtain a Hilbert space you need the norm induced by the inner product 
$$
\|f\|_{L^2}:=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}.
$$ 
to be complete. This can always be done.

I do not see any easy way to use any set of approximating functions on $[0,b]$.